# horizontal scroll not working after using word-break in td of table

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I just want to create a bootstrap table, with different width of td, and my columns are more, so I want one horizontal scroll bar, but after using word-break in any td, then scroll bar stop working.

given below is my example

CSS

```
 <style>
  .check {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  </style>
```

HTML

```
<div style=" overflow-x: auto; background: red">
    <table class="check">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Points</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style=" max-width:100px">
              john
              </td>
              <td
              style="
              max-width: 10px;
              word-reak: breakAall
              "
              >
            Smith
            </td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td style="max-width:200px;word-break:break-all">
            12000050000600000070000080000</td>
            <td style=" max-width:100px">50</td>
            <td style=" max-width:100px">50</td>
            <td style=" max-width:100px">50</td>
            <td style=" max-width:100px">50</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have another td that requires your scroll bar to appear. A scroll bar will appear if the width of your table extends past the width of the screen. The only td that requires you to have a scroll bar you have instructed to break the word instead. Many of your td's also have a MAX-width property. That means that your td will take up to 100px, but it can be less. Hence, none of those td's will force a scroll bar to appear either. The data you pose fits within the constraints of your screen width.

For example, this code will show a scroll bar because a td that does not have the word break styling is not present, and it forces the entire tr width to push past the screen width.

```
            <tr>
              <td style=" max-width:100px">
              john
              </td>
              <td
              style="
              max-width: 10px;
              word-reak: breakAall
              "
              >
            Smith
            </td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>12000050000600000070000080000</td>
            <td style="max-width:200px;word-break:break-all">
            12000050000600000070000080000</td>
            <td style=" max-width:100px">50</td>
            <td style=" max-width:100px">50</td>
            <td style=" max-width:100px">50</td>
            <td style=" max-width:100px">50</td>
        </tr>
```

see example here: https://jsfiddle.net/7am5e46b/

Comment: Then what is the solution. my td value is like, "AER124RTBJJKK5555555555YYY666666" and I want to set this in two lines only.